# Set an expiration of key for Electron-vue based application

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

I am building an electron-Vue desktop application which has a requirement that a key (used for setting expiration to particular section of application) should be valid till its expiration date(say 30 days). I should do programming such that,  after 30 days,  that particular part of application should be locked for the user but main problems are:
A) Desktop application is offline
B) If user change his/her desktop's time then also expiration must not get affected or delay in time.
I have googled a lot but could not find anything that can be used to solve this problem. I am writing code in javascript so VueJs or nodejs related solutions can be accepted. Thanks in advance! Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the local system time, use a timestamp. You can get the current timestamp by using `Date.now()` in JavaScript.
To read more about timestamps take a look at this: [Wikipedia - Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I can not use Date.now() as it will give time based on local system and as described in question what if user change his/her local system time which will result into getting changed time in electron desktop application(offline). So if user want the key will never expire based on his/her local system time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now As you can read here, Date.now() returns a unix timestamp. This is exactly what you are looking for, the timestamp won't change if the user changes their system time.

Comment: After googling abut Date.now() and Unix timestamp, I came at conclusion that Date.now() works by taking local system time and I have examined it myself practically. If you are suggesting about taking any web API, I can't because my desktop application is designed to work offline and so **A USER NEVER CONNECTS TO THE INTERNET** scenario can be taken as the worst case. Any other suggestions please!